# Custom datetime subclass that can be created from an existing datetime instance?

Tags: python, datetime, inheritance, python-datetime

I need to have a method to easily create an instance of a `datetime.datetime` subclass, given an existing `datetime.datetime()` instance.

Say I have the following contrived example:

```
class SerializableDateTime(datetime):
    def serialize(self):
        return self.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

I'm using a class like this (but a bit more complex), to use in a SQLAlchemy model; you can tell SQLAlchemy to map a custom class to a supported `DateTime` column value with a [`TypeDecorator` class](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types); e.g.:

```
class MyDateTime(types.TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.DateTime

    def process_bind_param(self, value, dialect):
        # from custom type to the SQLAlchemy type compatible with impl
        # a datetime subclass is fine here, no need to convert
        return value

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
        # from SQLAlchemy type to custom type
        # is there a way have this work without accessing a lot of attributes each time?
        return SerializableDateTime(value)   # doesn't work
```

I can't use `return SerializableDateTime(value)` here because the default `datetime.datetime.__new__()` method doesn't accept a `datetime.datetime()` instance:

```
>>> value = datetime.now()
>>> SerializableDateTime(value)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)
```

Is there a shortcut that avoids having to copy `value.year`, `value.month`, etc. all the way down to the timezone into a constructor?

Comment: @MartijnPieters The thing is that `value` is already of `datetime` type, but I can't initialize SerializableDateTime (which actually inherits `__init__` from `datetime`) with another `datetime` object. So `SerializableDateTime(value)` fails with `TypeError: an integer is required (got type datetime.datetime)`

Comment: That's not a SQLAlchemy issue, that's purely an issue with your custom class.

Comment: @MartijnPieters definitely, I didn't suspect this could be sqlalchemy issue

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although you can give your subclass a `__new__` method that detects a single `datetime.datetime` instance then does all the copying there, I'd actually give the class a classmethod just to handle this case, so your SQLAlchemy code would look like:

```
return SerializableDateTime.from_datetime(value)
```

We can make use of the `pickle` support the `datetime.datetime()` class already implements; types implement the [`__reduce_ex__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__reduce_ex__) (usually building on higher-level methods like [`__getnewargs__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#object.__getnewargs__)), and for `datetime.datetime()` instances this hook returns just the `datetime.datetime` type and an `args` tuple, meaning that as long as you have a subclass with the same internal state we can create a new copy with the same state by applying the `args` tuple back to your new type. The `__reduce_ex__` method can vary output by pickle protocol, but as long as you pass in [`pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) you are guaranteed to get the full supported range of values.

The `args` tuple consists of one or two values, the second being the timezone:

```
>>> from pickle import HIGHEST_PROTOCOL
>>> value = datetime.now()
>>> value.__reduce_ex__(HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
(<class 'datetime.datetime'>, (b'\x07\xe2\n\x1f\x12\x06\x05\rd\x8f',))
>>> datetime.utcnow().astimezone(timezone.utc).__reduce_ex__(value.__reduce_ex__(HIGHEST_PROTOCOL))
(<class 'datetime.datetime'>, (b'\x07\xe2\n\x1f\x12\x08\x14\n\xccH', datetime.timezone.utc))
```

That first value in the `args` tuple is a `bytes` value that represents all attributes of the object (excepting the timezone), and the constructor for `datetime` accepts that same bytes value (plus an optional timezone):

```
>>> datetime(b'\x07\xe2\n\x1f\x12\x06\x05\rd\x8f') == value
True
```

Since your subclass accepts the same arguments, you can make use of the `args` tuple to create a copy; we can use the first value to guard against changes in future Python versions by asserting it's still a parent class of ours:

```
from pickle import HIGHEST_PROTOCOL

class SerializableDateTime(datetime):
    @classmethod
    def from_datetime(cls, dt):
        """Create a SerializableDateTime instance from a datetime.datetime object"""
        # (ab)use datetime pickle support to copy state across
        factory, args = dt.__reduce_ex__(HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
        assert issubclass(cls, factory)
        return cls(*args)

    def serialize(self):
        return self.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
```

This lets you create instances of your subclass as a copy:

```
>>> SerializableDateTime.from_datetime(datetime.now())
SerializableDateTime(2018, 10, 31, 18, 13, 2, 617875)
>>> SerializableDateTime.from_datetime(datetime.utcnow().astimezone(timezone.utc))
SerializableDateTime(2018, 10, 31, 18, 13, 22, 782185, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)
```

While using the pickle `__reduce_ex__` hook may seem somewhat hackish, this is the actual protocol used to create copies of `datetime.datetime` instances with the [`copy` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) as well, and by using `__reduce_ex__(HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)` you ensure that all relevant state is copied whatever the Python version you are using.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! I've never met the reduce hook before, really interesting

Comment: @OlehRybalchenko: heads-up: I checked the datetime source code and was reminded of the fact that in Python 3.6 and up, [`datetime` objects have new `.fold` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-495-local-time-disambiguation) that would not be pickled in older pickle values but you probably want to bring along on newer Python versions. I've updated the answer to make sure you are future-proofed for further such additions.